# How do I match a word in a string with a key in a dict?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to look up a word in a string and match it with a key in a dict, like looking up a word in a dictionary in real life, e.g. look up `'vikings'` in dictionary:

```
poem = 'king of vikings kings'    
dictionary = {'king': 'regent', 'kings': 'regents', 'vikings: 'nords'}
```

I tried a for loop, but forgot that it would just iterate over each letter. I also tried to see if a key was in the string, and if it is then extract the key into another list.

However, in the example above, I only wanted `'vikings'` to show up, but if I used `if key in string`, the words `'king'`, and `'kings'` would also appear with `'vikings'`, as `'king'`, and `'kings'` both appear in the `'vikings'`.

Here's my code that's posing a problem:

```
for line in cap_poem_lines:
    line_to_analyze = [] 

    for key in word_to_phonemes:

        if key in line:

            line_to_analyze.extend([key])
            print(line_to_analyze)

return line_to_analyze
```

Comment: "I tried a for loop, but forgot that it would just iterate over each letter." You could always split up your string first (delimited by spaces), no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` separates words on a character (default is whitespace):

```
for word in poem.split(): 
    print d[word]
```